# Is it possible to iterate over collection via SendGrid API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendgrid

I want to dynamically generate a table with an undetermined number of rows (based on collection length) in a SendGrid template. Is this possible to do so in the template?

Is there a way to iterate over a collection?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not with SendGrid templates, but you can use a templating API/Service (like [sendwithus](https://www.sendwithus.com/)) which can support more complex templating languages.

Docs here if you're interested:
https://www.sendwithus.com/docs

These and similar services work on top of your SendGrid account.